# xpath в css selector, как правильно будет в моем случае?

Tags: xpath

```
//div[.='Как вам новая Почта?']/parent::*/parent::*
```

как будет выглядеть в css selector?

Comment: Насколько я помню, CSS-селекторы не позволяют искать по текстовому содержимому.

Comment: Вдобавок, помимо невозможности поиска по тексту, в css нет адекватного поиска по родительским нодам энного уровня вложенности, т.е. данный локатор невозможно преобразовать из xpath в css. Можете в этом убедиться в онлайн-конвертере xpath→css: [cssify](http://cssify.appspot.com/)